# Assign default value to reference variable

Tags: java

In Java if we declare primitive variable (not local) like int, float etc and do not initialize them, then they get initialized by their default values. Can we achieve something like this for reference variables? For example if I have an employee class which contains two int variables and in another class if I have created only reference of the employee class so is it possible that int variables get initialized by zero?

Comment: Can you give a code example? The terminology you're using is fairly imprecise, so much so that it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: I see there there might be misunderstanding between reference & object. Basically references and objects are different. references hold the object of same or sub type. references get space in stack and object gets space in heap. And I would refer you to google it to collect more concept regarding it.

Comment: rest assured, you will not read garbage, random data in a java program. everything is always zeroed first.

Answer (score 2):

> In Java if we declare primitive variable (not local) like int, float etc and do not initialize them, then they get initialized by their default values.

No, they don't. *Fields* do, both instance fields and class fields, but not *variables*.

> Can we achieve something like this for reference variables?

Reference fields get the same behavior. The value they're initialized with is `null`.

> For example if I have an employee class which contains two int variables and in another class if I have created only reference of the employee class so is it possible that int variables get initialized by zero?

If by "created a reference" you mean you've created an `Employee` instance, then any fields in that instance will be initialized to their defaults unless the `Employee` constructor gives them a different value.

Answer (score 1):

Fields are initialized to `null` if they are from some "type" (other than primitive types), anyway if you provide default values in your "default" constructor for that class in particular you can override the default `null` values for those.

```
final class Employee {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  // You can have more constructors here

  public Employee() {
    firstName = "Default Value for First Name";
    lastName = "Default Value for Last Name";
  }

  // Getters, Setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only not local fields are initialized to default values when not explicitly initialized. So, something like this

```
public class Main {
    boolean flag;
    void foo(){
        System.out.println(flag);
    }
}
```

compiles and `foo()` method would print `false`, while something like this

```
public class Main2 {
    void foo(){
        boolean flag;
        System.out.println(flag);
    }
}
```

wouldn't even compile. Furthermore, default value for a reference is `null`.

What you can do is designing your class in such a way that, when class is initialized, a value is assigne to its instance variables, something like

```
public class Main {
    boolean flag;
    {
        flag=true;
    }
    void foo(){
        System.out.println(flag);
    }
}
```